# How can I inspect what SUDs is generating/receiving in "sudo 0.4.1 jurko 5" and newer?

Tags: python, soap, suds

This question is similar to this one:

[How can I output what suds is generating/receiving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426204/how-can-i-output-what-suds-is-generating-receiving)

The problem is that I am using the [suds fork by Jurko](https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds) and after version "0.4.1 jurko 5" the `Client.last_sent()`, `Client.last_received()` methods have been removed. So the question is how can we replace their functionality on new suds versions?

PS. I know that I can decrease the debugging level but I would like if possible to be able to inspect the input/output programmatically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the MessagePlugin to do this

```
from suds.plugin import MessagePlugin

class LogPlugin(MessagePlugin):
  def sending(self, context):
    print(str(context.envelope))
  def received(self, context):
    print(str(context.reply))

client = Client("http://localhost/wsdl.wsdl", plugins=[LogPlugin()])
```